# Constrain Mapbox panning north/south only?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Anyone know how to constrain the panning in a Mapbox map only using north/south bounds? What I would like to do is use the world copy so that users can continuously pan east to west, but restrict the north and south panning so that you can't pan outside of the map tiles (which I find super annoying). I'm currently using a maxbounds when initializing the map to prevent panning into the white tiles above and below the poles, but that's a no-go with world copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-Infinity` west, and `Infinity` east (thnx Ivan) in the `L.LatLngBounds` you use for setting the `maxBounds` option: (using Leaflet in the snippet but should work for Mapbox.js too)

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 2,
    'worldCopyJump': true,
    'layers': [
        new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        }),
        new L.Marker([0,0])
    ],
    'maxBounds': [
        [-90, -Infinity],
        [90, Infinity]
    ]
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also use `Infinity` and `-Infinity` instead of `360` and `-360`.

Comment: That looks way cleaner/better, i'll change my answer, thnx.